# PHP - How to merge two different JSON outputs into one

Tags: php, json, parsing, echo

### My php server is generating two JSON output

1.] For MySql JSON printing I am using this code.

```
$sql = "select id ,Title , Meassage from lodhinews";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$values = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $values['data'][] = array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'Title'=>$row['Title'],
        'Meassage'=>$row['Meassage']    
    );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($values ,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
} else {
$values = array(
    'error'=>'No results found'
);

}
$conn->close();
?>
```

2.]  For file name printing I am using this code

```
chdir('./uploads');
foreach(glob('*.*') as $filename){
$data[] = $filename; 
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

both the above code is working fine!

**I wanted this both json output combined on one single page**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... what is the current output, and what is the desired output?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan current output is like {
    `"data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "Title": "t1",
            "Meassage": "n1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "Title": "tdsfds",
            "Meassage": "n1dsvfcsd"
        }] ` and 2nd json is like `["Untitled.png","logo40.png"]`  I wanted both in one json like `{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "Title": "t1",
            "Meassage": "n1" 
   "upload:Untiled.png"
        }]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not very complicated ! :)

```
$merged_array = array();
$merged_array[] = $data;
$merged_array[] = $values;
print json_encode($merged_array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: @Robert and Halayem , it is giving 2 different json object eg. [some data] , [some data] . But i wanted both inside of single json object like [somedata]